# Activating a VPN on Google Cloud Compute VM is terminating my connection

Tags: rdp, google-cloud-platform

I have spun up a Google Cloud Compute virtual machine. It's a vanilla Windows Server 2016 image, and I can log in and see the desktop. I do that by downloading the RDP file and running it.

Due to a license manager for software I'm installing, I need to VPN to my own network. In "Settings -> Network", I add a new VPN connection (using the same creds I use on my machine) and click Connect. It makes an initial connection, verifies my credentials, but during the final stage, my RDP connection to the GCP VM ends.

What is really strange is that, sometimes, I can reconnect successfully after a few minutes and the VPN connection was successful. Sometimes I can't reconnect.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VPN connection added as such will be a force tunneled VPN which then adds a default route over the VPN interface on the VM disrupting your connection. The easiest way for maintaining the connection would be to do either of 2 things

1. Make the VPN split tunneled and add a route for the licensing box. You can do this by using the Set-VPNConnection Powershell commandlet and then adding a route using the route add command in an administrative command prompt
2. Add a more specific route for the IP Address by which u access the VM using the route add command

**UPDATE**: Simply setting the VPN to use split tunneling in PowerShell solved the problem.
**Use:** (Replace "VPNsName" with your VPNs Name)

```
Set-VpnConnection -Name "VPNsName" -SplitTunneling 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm not very knowledgeable about this. I've made it as far as setting the VPN to use SplitTunneling in PowerShell. I've read a few articles on the route add command, but I'm not understanding. If the license box is at 1.1.1.1, the VM is at 2.2.2.2, and my home router's external-facing IP address is 3.3.3.3, what is the command I need on the VM's cmd line? Here's what I've got so far: "route -p ADD 1.1.1.1"

Comment: Actually, after setting the VM to splittunneling, I just tried to connect. It worked! I'll try it a few more times to make sure it's not some kind of lucky fluke, but then I'll answer the question.

Comment: Usually what happens is that once u make the VPN split tunneled automatically one route will be added based on the class of address assigned on that interface. For eg. If your VPN server assigns a route of 10.0.0.0/8 range, automatically a route for the entire class A which is from 10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255 will be added For the VPN interface. (look up class based addressing for the rest of the breakdowns)